# Guessing date format for many identically-formatted dates in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a large set of datetime strings and it can be safely assumed that they're all identically formatted. For example, I might have the set of dates "7/1/13 0:45", "5/2/13 6:21", "7/15/13 1:24", "7/9/13 12:41", "4/30/13 3:12". The idea would be to get their common format with a reasonable amount of reliability so that they can be parsed using strptime or similar.

Is there any easy way to guess the format? Ideally a library that does this?

Comment: Can your possible date format be expressed as a finite set of previusly known formats? If so, you could try to estimate the best one by bruteforce: for each of the known formats, **try** to parse each date. Count the number of success for each format. Get the format that has succeded most times. (You could also try all the existing date formats :p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/jeffreystarr/dateinfer

Seems a little abandoned but maybe it will go with your needs.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Comment: it doesn't work in this case: `dateinfer.infer(["7/1/13 0:45", "5/2/13 6:21", "7/15/13 1:24", "7/9/13 12:41", "4/30/13 3:12"])` -> `'%m/%d/%d %H:%M'` but it should be `'%m/%d/%y %H:%M'`

Comment: Would you believe I ended up implementing my own solution with an almost identical design? https://github.com/humangeo/DateSense/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) on the tokenized time strings from the set?

It's often very robust to a wide range of formats, or from errors you get it becomes obvious how to slightly massage your data into a format that it works with.

```
In [11]: dateutil.parser.parse("7/1/13 0:45")
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 1, 0, 45)
```

Do take care of ambiguities in the data. For example, it doesn't look like your time stamps use 24 hours, but instead would report "3:00 pm" and "3:00 am" identically on the same date. Unless you have some way of assigning am / pm to the data, no parser can help you out of that issue.

If your date strings are stored in an `iterable` then you can use `map` to apply the parse function to all of the strings:

```
In [12]: the_dates = ["7/1/13 0:45", "12/2/14 1:38", "4/30/13 12:12"]

In [13]: map(dateutil.parser.parse, the_dates)
Out[13]: 
[datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 1, 0, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 2, 1, 38),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 12, 12)]
```

And if you are in need of some of the extra arguments to `dateutil.parser.parse` that will indicate the formatting to use, you can use `functools.partial` to first bind those keyword arguments, and then use `map` as above to apply the partial function.

For example, suppose you wanted to be extra careful that DAY is treated as the first number. You could always call `parse` with the extra argument `dayfirst=True`, or you could pre-bind this argument and treat it like a new function that always had this property.

```
In [42]: import functools

In [43]: new_parse = functools.partial(dateutil.parser.parse, dayfirst=True)

In [44]: map(new_parse, the_dates)
Out[44]: 
[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 0, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 12, 1, 38),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 12, 12)]

In [45]: new_parse.keywords 
Out[45]: {'dayfirst': True}

In [46]: new_parse.func 
Out[46]: <function dateutil.parser.parse>
```

(Note that in this example, the third date cannot be parsed with day-first, since neither 30 nor 13 can be a month... so it falls back to the default format in that case).

Comment: which is the day and month in `"7/1/13 0:45" and "1/7/13 0:45"`?

Comment: You can control that with some of the other args. I believe the default is the American standard, with month first, but check the documentation to be sure.

Comment: As far as I could tell dateutil.parser wasn't fit for parsing sets of dates, I don't know of any way to tell it "all of these have the same format". If it's capable - how? I'm completely aware of the ambiguities but it's not an issue in this case. It doesn't need to be completely accurate, just a close guess.

Comment: Just use `map` to apply the function to the whole set of dates. Or even (gasp) a `for` loop.

Comment: In which case it guesses for each date regardless of whether the same format fits the others. All the dates are the same format. Also, it's important that I get the date format and not the date itself.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. It does not guess the date, it has a clear, deterministic protocol it uses for choosing a format, which starts with any of the keyword arguments you use to tell it the format. What do you mean by "it's important that I get the date format and not the date itself"? Is your question: when given a series of dates in the same format, how do I work backwards to some description of the format? If so, then my question is why? Date parsing tools do that for you. That is in fact exactly what they do.

Comment: You're spot-on with what the question is. What date parsing tools do this, and where can I find them?

Comment: I'm saying that that is a misguided question. "what is the date format" depends entirely on what you plan to do with the data. How would you tell a date parser to parse the dates for the sake of your program? If you can't answer that question, then there is no such thing as some kind of Platonic "format" of your data. It's just characters in a string. However, you *can* tell a date parsing tool like `dateutil` what assumptions to make about the strings and to then parse it. But you cannot ask a parser to tell you what assumptions *you* should make about the string, for that depends on your use

Comment: I need a date format like what would be passed to strptime. I need to present this information to the user for verification before the dates are actually parsed. Not following how this is misguided.

Comment: Why are you using `strptime`? In the location where you plan to call `strptime`, why don't you instead call `dateutil.parser.parse`? You can ask the user to provide answers to questions, like "date first" or to even type in a string like "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" which `parse` accepts. I say it is misguided because you seem to look at it like `strptime` based on user-validated known-in-advance format is the *only* thing you can do, but it's not, and it's not a good way to do this.

Comment: It doesn't have to be strptime. The format does need to be consistent across all the parsed dates. It does need to go to the user for verification before all the data is actually parsed, because there can potentially be quite a lot of dates and doing it wrong is bad. It does need to be something standard, anyone who's working with the application will know how to read and use strptime's format input.

Comment: Then it seems that `dateutil.parser.parse` satisifes everything you need, exactly as I've written it above. You can ask the user to type in a valid formatting string as per the documentation of `parse`.